# .plist not keeping process alive

Tags: macos, plist, launchctl

I am trying to setup FreeRADIUS on a Mac Server. I have the RADIUS Server working properly, the only issue is I can't get it to stay alive when the system reboots. The following is a plist I have in /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freeradius.radiusd.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.freeradius.radiusd</string>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mycommand.err</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/mycommand.out</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/bin/radiusd</string>
      <string>-X</string>
      <string>-d</string>
      <string>/usr/local/etc/raddb</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

After I restart and then use the following command

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freeradius.radiusd.plist
```

the server launches fine without any issues and it stays alive.

I've had a look at output in /tmp/mycommand.out (.err is empty) and the last couple of lines are:

```
Listening on auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address * port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address :: port 1812 bound to server default
Listening on acct address :: port 1813 bound to server default
Listening on auth address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 bound to server inner-tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 53565
Listening on proxy address :: port 53566
Ready to process requests
```

so it seems to be launching okay.

I have also checked the permissions on the plist and they are the following

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   738 27 Jun 11:41 org.freeradius.radiusd.plist
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try removing `<key>EnableTransactions</key><true/>`.

Comment: @l'L'l that didn't work, but now in my /tmp/mycommand.out I'm getting
```Signalled to terminate Exiting normally```

Comment: When you run it from the command-line what is output in mycommand.out?